# How to set read timeout using apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soap-client, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using apache's commons-httpclient.jar to call SOAP service. I'm setting the connection timeout and socket timeout as shown below. How to set the read timeout using org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient ? Can someone please suggest?

`httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 1000);`
`httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.timeout", 1000);`

Comment: Hi. Which version of apache common are you using? As specified in this article for version 2.1 [Apache common httpclient](http://2min2code.com/articles/apache_http_client_intro/setting_timeout_get) the socket timeout is actually the read timeout. Additionally you should take a look at this article from Baeldung [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout)

Comment: Thank you. I have realized that socket is read timeout.